Searching a text column for keywords very slow
I have a SQL Server database that only has a single table with a few columns. There are a few thousand rows currently. The columns are as follows:
id (nvarchar(35))
path (nvarchar(255))
body (ntext)
datetimecreated (datetime)
author (nvarchar(255))
version (int)
summary (nvarchar(255))

The search query is as follows:
SELECT [id],[path],[body],[datetimecreated],[author],[version],[summary]
  FROM [dbo].[pages] p1
  where     ([version] =
                  (select     max(p2.[version])
                   from          [dbo].[pages] p2
                   where      p1.[path] = p2.[path]))       
and (body like '%outlook%'
or summary like '%outlook%'
or author like '%outlook%'
)
order by   p1.[path] asc

A search like above will take 8-10 seconds to complete. I've tried copying the db and converting the ntext to nvarchar(max) and see no difference in query times. I've also tried creating a full-text index and searching with the following:
contains (body, '"outlook"') or CONTAINS (summary, '"outlook"')

This actually takes longer.
I'm looking for advice/help to speed up search queries. I did not design the database.
I've tried modifying the body column to nvarchar(max) and creating a full-text index to no avail.
Here's the execution plan:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.589" Build="16.0.5564.30211" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120" StatementSubTreeCost="1.90059" StatementText="SELECT TOP 1000 [id]&#xD;&#xA;      ,[path]&#xD;&#xA;      ,[body]&#xD;&#xA;      ,[datetimecreated]&#xD;&#xA;      ,[author]&#xD;&#xA;      ,[version]&#xD;&#xA;      ,[summary]&#xD;&#xA;  FROM [dbo].[pages_1] p1&#xD;&#xA;  where     ([version] =&#xD;&#xA;                  (select     max(p2.[version])&#xD;&#xA;                   from          [dbo].[pages_1] p2&#xD;&#xA;                   where      p1.[path] = p2.[path]))        &#xD;&#xA;and (body like '%outlook%'&#xD;&#xA;or summary like '%outlook%'&#xD;&#xA;/*or author like '%outlook%'*/&#xD;&#xA;)&#xD;&#xA;order by   p1.[path] asc" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x91AAE73160CEF12C" QueryPlanHash="0xE33814DCBC42ED0F" RetrievedFromCache="true" StatementSqlHandle="0x09003CE69250B7708CCD87CBDE6C4A7A08DE0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" DatabaseContextSettingsId="12" ParentObjectId="0" StatementParameterizationType="0" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" MemoryGrant="1424" CachedPlanSize="48" CompileTime="399" CompileCPU="63" CompileMemory="512">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="640" SerialDesiredMemory="1424" RequiredMemory="640" DesiredMemory="1424" RequestedMemory="1424" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="1424" MaxUsedMemory="520" MaxQueryMemory="401408" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="47815008" EstimatedPagesCached="5976876" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" MaxCompileMemory="1349624" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="4855" EstimateCPU="1E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Top" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Top" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.90059">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="id" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="body" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="datetimecreated" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="author" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="version" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="summary" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="4" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="8595" ActualCPUms="701" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Top RowCount="false" IsPercent="false" WithTies="false">
                <TopExpression>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1000)">
                    <Const ConstValue="(1000)" />
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </TopExpression>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="4855" EstimateCPU="0.00586661" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Merge Join" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.90059">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="id" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="body" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="datetimecreated" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="author" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="version" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="summary" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="4" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="8595" ActualCPUms="701" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Merge ManyToMany="false">
                    <InnerSideJoinColumns>
                      <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                    </InnerSideJoinColumns>
                    <OuterSideJoinColumns>
                      <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="path" />
                    </OuterSideJoinColumns>
                    <Residual>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Expr1002]=[wiki].[dbo].[pages_1].[version] as [p1].[version] AND [wiki].[dbo].[pages_1].[path] as [p2].[path]=[wiki].[dbo].[pages_1].[path] as [p1].[path]">
                        <Logical Operation="AND">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="version" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="path" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Logical>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Residual>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="65" EstimateCPU="0.0016498" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="98" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.969562">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="path" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="98" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="3" ActualCPUms="3" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <StreamAggregate>
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="MAX([wiki].[dbo].[pages_1].[version] as [p2].[version])">
                              <Aggregate AggType="MAX" Distinct="false">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="version" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Aggregate>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <GroupBy>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="path" />
                        </GroupBy>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="65" EstimateCPU="0.047471" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="2668" LogicalOp="Sort" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.967912">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="path" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="version" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="0.734694" />
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="2668" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="3" ActualCPUms="3" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" InputMemoryGrant="1296" OutputMemoryGrant="704" UsedMemoryGrant="280" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <Sort Distinct="false">
                            <OrderBy>
                              <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="path" />
                              </OrderByColumn>
                            </OrderBy>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="65" EstimateCPU="0.0030918" EstimateIO="0.906088" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="2668" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.90918" TableCardinality="2668">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="path" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="version" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="2668" ActualRowsRead="2668" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="1" ActualCPUms="1" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="1247" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                              </RunTimeInformation>
                              <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                <DefinedValues>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="path" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" Column="version" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <Object Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Index="[PK_pages_1]" Alias="[p2]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                              </IndexScan>
                            </RelOp>
                          </Sort>
                        </RelOp>
                      </StreamAggregate>
                    </RelOp>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="4855" EstimateCPU="0.000235967" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="19.5838" LogicalOp="Sort" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.925159">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="id" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="body" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="datetimecreated" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="author" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="version" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="summary" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <MemoryFractions Input="0.265306" Output="0.265306" />
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="79" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="8592" ActualCPUms="697" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" InputMemoryGrant="712" OutputMemoryGrant="328" UsedMemoryGrant="240" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <Sort Distinct="false">
                        <OrderBy>
                          <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                          </OrderByColumn>
                        </OrderBy>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="4855" EstimateCPU="0.00448224" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="19.5838" LogicalOp="Filter" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Filter" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.913662">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="id" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="body" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="datetimecreated" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="author" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="version" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="summary" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="79" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="8591" ActualCPUms="697" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <Filter StartupExpression="false">
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="4855" EstimateCPU="0.0030918" EstimateIO="0.906088" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="2668" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="7" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.90918" TableCardinality="2668">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="id" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="body" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="datetimecreated" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="author" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="version" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="summary" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="2668" ActualRowsRead="2668" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="653" ActualCPUms="3" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="1247" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                              </RunTimeInformation>
                              <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                <DefinedValues>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="id" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="path" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="body" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="datetimecreated" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="author" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="version" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="summary" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <Object Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Index="[PK_pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                              </IndexScan>
                            </RelOp>
                            <Predicate>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[wiki].[dbo].[pages_1].[body] as [p1].[body] like N'%outlook%' OR [wiki].[dbo].[pages_1].[summary] as [p1].[summary] like N'%outlook%'">
                                <Logical Operation="OR">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Intrinsic FunctionName="like">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="body" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Const ConstValue="N'%outlook%'" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Intrinsic>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Intrinsic FunctionName="like">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[wiki]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pages_1]" Alias="[p1]" Column="summary" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Const ConstValue="N'%outlook%'" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Intrinsic>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Logical>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Predicate>
                          </Filter>
                        </RelOp>
                      </Sort>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Merge>
                </RelOp>
              </Top>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>


Please use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to paste your plan.

Regardless of the final solution you should probably migrate away from image, ntext and text data types as those have been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005 (migrate to varbinary(max), nvarchar(max) and varchar(max) respectively). Ref: ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL).

While it can be helpful in some situations Full-Text Search isn't always a magical performance booster. See, for example: Why Full Text’s CONTAINS Queries Are So Slow.

Any query for a fragment of a string within a larger string, is likely to be slow.

Are you sure the execution plan you have posted is for the full text index? Because all I can see are table scans.

Contains cannot do wildcard start search. These kind of queries will always be slow, the only mitigation is to create an index containing the text columns so it at least doesn't have to trawl through the clustered one, but it might not help enough either

Sounds like path isn't indexed either, judging by your slow result. Maybe break down your query into two, where first one fetches the last version and the second does the text matching

The presented query execution plan shows that 96% of the time (cost) is spent on fetching the row with the maximum version. It seems unlikely to me. However, try to make a selection using row_number()(partition by path order by version desc) rn and rn=1. And provide the actual data on the execution of the request

@AlwaysLearning understood, and yes, I am doing that with this DB, although it has no effect of performance.

@siggemannen thanks for the idea. I made a first query that gets the latest version of all pages and then a second that queries the resultset from the first for the search term. The total time for my testing thus far has dropped to about 2 seconds (4x faster)!

I first converted the body field to varchar(max) (which didn't yield any performance increase) and then broke this into two queries where the first gets the latest version of each page and the second is a query of queries that looks for the search phrase. This results in an average of 2 seconds per result, a 4-5x speed increase. Thanks!
The first query:
select     [id], [path], [body], [datetimecreated], [author], [version], [summary]
from       pages p1
where     (version =
          (select     max(p2.version)
          from          pages p2
          where      p1.path = p2.path))
order by   p1.path asc

The second query:
select id, path, datetimecreated, version
from    latest
where (body like '%outlook%'
      or summary like '%outlook%')
order by path asc


There could be two improvements in your query.

it executes the subquery for each row due your where condition in the subquery so you can query it using INNER JOIN by deriving the table having max version only.
You have multiple OR condition in the main where clause which may not use your index properly even if you have created the full-text search index. You may try by converting the query into UNIONS to solve this.

Below is the modified query you can use. If you are not going to use the Index then use like instead of contains as it may be overhead but if you are using index then you can use it to get the power of the Index.
SELECT [id],[path],[body],[datetimecreated],[author],[version],[summary]
  FROM [dbo].[pages] p1
  INNER JOIN 
    (select     max(p2.[version]) as latest_version, p2.[path] as path
     from [dbo].[pages] p2
     group by p2.[path]
    ) X ON X.path = p1.path and X.latest_version = p1.version
where contains (body, '"outlook"')
order by   p1.[path] asc
UNION
SELECT [id],[path],[body],[datetimecreated],[author],[version],[summary]
  FROM [dbo].[pages] p1
  INNER JOIN 
    (select     max(p2.[version]) as latest_version, p2.[path] as path
     from [dbo].[pages] p2
     group by p2.[path]
    ) X ON X.path = p1.path and X.latest_version = p1.version
where CONTAINS(summary, '"outlook"')
order by   p1.[path] asc
UNION
SELECT [id],[path],[body],[datetimecreated],[author],[version],[summary]
  FROM [dbo].[pages] p1
  INNER JOIN 
    (select     max(p2.[version]) as latest_version, p2.[path] as path
     from [dbo].[pages] p2
     group by p2.[path]
    ) X ON X.path = p1.path and X.latest_version = p1.version
where CONTAINS (author, '"outlook"')
order by   p1.[path] asc


Tried your query, no improvement in performance, but thanks for the idea!
